# TimeDistributed with different input / output sequence length

Tags: neural-network, lstm, rnn

I'm looking into using `TimeDistributed` in my LSTM to see if it would improve the accuracy of my model.  I'll be honest, I'm still not 100% sure what the specific use case for `TimeDistributed`, I just thought I'd give it a try and see if it improved my accuracy. Aside from blind trial/error, why would someone use `TimeDistributed`?

Now, my next question is probably tied to my lack of understanding of exactly what `TimeDistributed`'s specific use case is, but I understand that the output from `TimeDistributed` is a sequence, and that sequence is the same length as the input sequence because you use `return_sequences=True` on the final layer of the model (all of them in my case, as it's stateful).

In my case I'm inputting a sequence which is 100 length, and I'm then forecasting a sequence of length 3 from that input sequence, but I get this error:

> Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_1 to have shape
>   (100, 3) but got array with shape (3, 1)

Am I right in assuming that you can only use `TimeDistributed` if your output sequence is the same length as the input sequence?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have looked for an answer to this question for quite a while, and couldn't really find a clear yes/no answer.

From what I understand, TimeDistributed really only works for similar input/output lengths. 
According to what Jason Brownlee writes in the comments section of his [TimeDistributed tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/), he would treat the different input/output lengths as a seq2seq/encoder-decoder problem (which he describes [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/encoder-decoder-long-short-term-memory-networks/)).

If you find a better answer, or find a way to make TimeDistributed work with different output sizes, please let me know.

---

### *Update (copying my comment from below, with better formatting):

Actually, I have found a different solution which does use TimeDistributed: You can trim the output sequence you get from `TimeDistributed` using `Cropping1D` layer. So that my model now looks like this:

```
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(num_input_timepoints, 1) ,dropout=0.05)
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1))) 
model.add(Cropping1D(cropping=(num_input_timepoints - num_output_timepoints,0))) # cropping the end
```

Which, in your case, would trim the first 97 time points and would leave you with the last 3. That would fit the shape of your target data.

Comment: I should have updated my question with my findings because yes, I found the same as yourself; that the output from TimeDistributed must be the same as the input.  But I'm pleased someone came to the same conclusion as I did - we BOTH can't be wrong, surely  ;-)   I'd still like to know what the actual use case for TimeDistributed is, i.e. why would you use it...?

Comment: Actually, I have found a different solution which does use TimeDistributed:
You can trim the output sequence you get from TimeDistributed using Cropping1D.
So that my model now looks like this:
```
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(num_input_timepoints, 1) ,dropout=0.05))  
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))  
model.add(Cropping1D(cropping=(num_input_timepoints - num_output_timepoints,0))) # cropping the end
```  
Which, in your case, would trim the first 97 time points and would leave you with the last 3. That would fit the shape of your target data.

Comment: From what I've read, you use a TimeDistributed layer because you *want* the output to be the same length as the input. I think cropping it in this way actually undermines the whole point of using a TD layer, and it's probably just best to use a regular Dense layer with 3 outputs (in my case). But I'm still none the wiser 'why' you'd use a TD even if you had same lengths input/output; what effect does it have?

Answer (score 0):

Linking [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46672/how-to-design-a-many-to-many-lstm/61342#61342).

My understanding (which I am still working on) is to set an initial LSTM layer with your input sequence and `return_sequences` set to `False`. Then add a `RepeatVector` layer which simply repeats the output from your last timestep of the above LSTM layer N times. Input this into another LSTM layer with `return_sequences=True` and a final `TimeDistributed(Dense(1))` layer.

Like so:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = UNITS , input_shape = (input_shape), return_sequences = False)) 
model.add(RepeatVector(N))  
model.add(LSTM(UNITS, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

I am getting this from the linked post I've provided. This makes intuitive sense to me for the following reasons:

For a "many to many" LSTM model with varying output size, the first LSTM layer learns the pattern of the first `timesteps` number of samples and makes a prediction for the last timestep; the `RepeatVector` layer then repeats this output N times. The next LSTM layer uses this same output prediction as the first hidden state fed into each of the timesteps we are trying to predict (I think). I would really like some clarification on this part.

Finally, the `TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))` passes each timestep you are wanting to predict into a single `Dense` node for the final prediction. This returns an output vector of `(timesteps, feature(s?))`.

Note: I think this is a particularly tricky problem and is a workaround for a type of problem that Keras doesn't explicitly support. I would appreciate any corrections from more folks more experienced in the field, as I'm still learning as well!