# How to design a many-to-many LSTM?

Tags: lstm

I have an input array of shape (1000,20, 4) and output(labels) of shape (1000,25,1). But don't know how to use Keras LSTM library to build a sequential model for this!

Can someone help me design a simple LSTM for doing that? (I tried to use `RepeatVector()` and `TimeDistributed(Dense())` in several ways but I get errors like the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = un , input_shape = (20, 4), return_sequences = False)) 
model.add(RepeatVector(25))  
model.add(LSTM(un , return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20)))
```

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_419 to have
>   shape (25, 20) but got array with shape (25, 1)

Comment: Can you provide some more code on how you designed the model?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal: I edited my question.

Comment: In the last layer change `Dense( 20 )` to `Dense( 1 )`.

Comment: It worked! How is it possible? How does it work?  Please explain more in an answer and I will accept it. I read about repeat and time distributed layers but still I can't understand how do they exactly work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the labels array was ( 25 , 1 ). The shape of your previous model was ( 25 , 20 ). The dimension 20 was because of this line.

`model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20)))`

The `Dense` layer had an output dimension in the form of `units=` argument  as 20. 25 was the length of the sequence.

> So, on each of the 25 timesteps, a `Dense` layer operation was done and
>   each produced a array of shape ( 20 , ). This process happened for 25
>   timesteps which resulted in a final output of shape ( 25, 20 ).

**`RepeatVector`** : It repeats the input vector given to it `n` number of times.

**`Timedistributed`**: Executes the layer operation which is wrapped in it ( in your case it was `Dense` layer ) for every timestep in the given input sequence.

To know more about the above layers, refer to this [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46491/what-is-the-job-of-repeatvector-and-timedistributed/46504) of mine.

Hence, In the last layer changing `Dense( 20 )` to `Dense( 1 )` will correct the vector dimension.